# How to authenticate to a salesforce instance and make an API call on submission of a form?

Tags: rest-api

I'm essentially using a basic HTMl, CSS, Javascript form to have my potential customers submit their interest to my site, and I'd like to have the form make a call upon submission to my Salesforce instance and check whether there is an existing lead in my instance based on that email address and if so, return the information about that lead.

I'm not trying to build an entire app, just have this one call authenticate and return the lead's information, but I'm having trouble finding the best way to include this logic without exposing IDs or passwords in the authentication process.

Comment: Are you trying to do this all "client side" or can you run some server code?

Comment: There's some _very_ serious security implications here, both in terms of authentication and exposing your CRM data via a highly scrapable API. Instead, consider using a standard web-to-lead form and managing deduplication in your CRM.

Comment: I can run some server code if necessary but was hoping to achieve it client side if at all possible.

The security concerns are what I'm trying to find a workable solution to avoid, I can't use a web to lead form, as I'm trying to offer different resources and solutions based on the response of the API call.